# Combine lists alternating elements one by one or two by two

Tags: list, python-itertools, pairwise

I have 4 lists:

```
a = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8"]

b = ["b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6"]

c = ["c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"]

d = ["d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7"]
```

I need to create a list alternating the elements one by one until possible, BUT for the last list I need to take them 2 by 2 (also until possible). So the result should be:

```
new_list = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "d2", "a2", "b2", "c2", "d3", "d4", "a3", "b3", 
            "c3", "d5", "d6", "a4", "b4", "c4", "d7", "a5", "b5", "c5", "a6", "b6", 
            "a7", "a8"]
```

I know for alternating one by one you could use itertools like:

```
import itertools
book_list = [x for x in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.zip_longest(a,b, c, d)) if x is not None]
```

But I do I make sure for list d I take 2 elements instead of just one? Can I introduce a pairwise() somehow on list d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an iterator from `d` and `zip` it twice to draw from the sequence twice per iteration:

```
d2 = iter(d)
new_list = list(filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, c, d2, d2))))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MarriedOrderlyPoint

Comment: That's right, thanks! I actually came up with my own solution (which I have just posted below) not long after posting the question.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve it trivially by dividing list d into 2 lists, one with its even elements, and the other with its odd ones.

```
d_even = d[0::2]
d_odds = d[1::2]
```

And then add both to the zip:

```
new_list = list(filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, c, d_even, d_odd))))
```